# Dotcloud + MongoDB and pymongo authenticantion failed

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, bottle, dotcloud

I have tried this code on my mongoshell in dotcloud but it is not authenticating the root user.

dotcloud run data mongo

use admin
db.auth("root", "SecurePasswordGoesHere");

Error: { errmsg: "auth fails", ok: 0.0 }
0

How can I get this to work? I'm trying to accesss the mongodb from pymongo an it also returning authentication error.

Comment: I just solve it...suhauhsuahuas. For some reason de mongo server was down on amazon machine...I just created another service and voila!

Comment: I edited your question, to remove your password.

Comment: Thanks Ken...that wasn't a real password I just got that from an example. If you check at dotcloud mongodb example page you should find the same password and username. But anyway I really appreciate that.